# All the checkboxes inside a ng-repeat are getting checked when I select just one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-checked

I have list of objects named rolePermissionList like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"createUser","type":"user","marked":1},{"id":2,"name":"deleteUser","type":"user","marked":1},{"id":3,"name":"editRole","type":"role","marked":0}]
```

and I use `ng-repeat`  to repeat checkboxes using the values in that list like this

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Role Permissions:</label>
    <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="permission in rolePermissionList">
       <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="idsPermission[permission .idPermission ]"
               ng-checked="permission.checked">{{permission.name}}
       </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

the `ng-model` of the checkboxes is named `idsPermission` and it's a list of numbers, those numbers are the IDS of the objects.

When I load the page the checkboxes that are supposed to be checked are checked this part works fine, but when I check another checkbox all the checkboxes gets checked, and when I uncheck a checkbox the same thing happens all the checkboxes gets unchecked.

I use that list of numbers named `idsPermission` to get all the IDS of the checkboxes that are checked, this worked before I used the directive `ng-checked="permission.checked"`, but now I need to use it since now I need to show the checkboxes that are already marked.

this is my controller

```
angular.module('MyApp')
    .controller('RolCtrl', ['$scope', 'RolService',
        function ($scope, RolService) {
            $scope.idsPermission = {};
            $scope.getListCheckBoxesEditRole = function (idRole) {

                $scope.selectRol.descripcion;
                RolService.getListCheckBoxesEditRole(idRole)
                        .then(
                                function (d) {
                                    var userPermissionList = [];
                                    for (var permission in  d) {
                                        if (d[permission ].type === 'user') {
                                            if (d[permission ].marked === 1)
                                            {
                                                d[permission ].checked = true;
                                                userPermissionList.push(d[permission ]);
                                            } else {
                                                userPermissionList.push(d[permission ]);
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                    $scope.rolePermissionList = userPermissionList;
                                },
                                function (errResponse) {
                                    console.error('ERROR');
                                }
                        );
            };
        }
        $scope.getListCheckBoxesEditRole(3);
    ]);
```

The RolService.getListCheckBoxesEditRole(idRole) service returns this JSON `[{"id":1,"name":"createUser","type":"user","marked":1},{"id":2,"name":"deleteUser","type":"user","marked":1},{"id":3,"name":"editRole","type":"role","marked":0}]`

and what I do in the controller is iterate over that list and check if the marked field is `1` if it's `1` I do this `d[permission ].checked = true;` I what I think that I do in that line is setting the checked value to true so I could use this directive in the html view `ng-checked="permission.checked"`

I tried doing this  `ng-checked="idsPermission[permission.checked]"` but when I do this the values that are `marked=1` in the JSON that I paste above don't appear checked when I load the page, but if I put it like this `ng-checked="permission.checked"` they appear marked as they should, but when I click a checkbox all the checkboxes gets selected.

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score 0):

I came across too many issues to document but the main problem was how you are iterating through the array that is returned from the service.  It should be something like this:

**Controller**

```
    angular.forEach(d.data, function(permission) {
       if (permission.type === 'user') {
        if (permission.marked === 1) {
          permission.checked = true;
          userPermissionList.push(permission);
        } else {
          userPermissionList.push(permission);
        }
      }
    });
```

Then you can simplify your html like this:

**HTML**

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="permission.checked" />
```

You can see all of the changes in this working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/QIbTE3suXIXRg1JOkCGo).

Answer (score 0):

I can't see in your code that `$scope.idsPermission` is getting defined. In `ng-repeat` you only set the key for the object but the value is `undefined`. That's why the checkbox won't show the correct value.

You could use `ng-init` to initialize the model. Please have a look at the simplified demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/0ufzcfzr/).

(Also defining the models in your controller would be possible.)

Only using `ng-model` should be enough for the checkbox to work. I think I've read somewhere that `ng-checked` and `ng-model` aren't working smoothly together.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl() {
  var vm = this;

  angular.extend(vm, {
    data: [{
      id: 0,
      marked: 1
    }, {
      id: 1,
      marked: 0
    }, {
      id: 2,
      marked: 1
    }]
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in ctrl.data">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-init="ctrl.idPermissions[item.id] = !!item.marked" ng-model="ctrl.idPermissions[item.id]"/>{{item.id}}
  </div>

  <pre>
permissions: {{ctrl.idPermissions | json: 2}}
data{{ctrl.data | json: 2}}</pre>

</div>
```